# Why does my code return unicode characters?

Tags: java, url, inputstreamreader

```
String encodedInputText = URLEncoder.encode("input=" + question, "UTF-8");
            urlStr = Parameters.getWebserviceURL();
            URL url = new URL(urlStr + encodedInputText + "&sku=" + sku);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
            jsonOutput = in.readLine();
            in.close();
```

The problem is that the returned JSON string contains all unicodes like

```
"question":"\u51e0\u5339\u7684",
```

Not the actual Chinese characters. The "UTF-8" should solve the problem. Why doesn't it?

EDIT:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ResponseList = responseList = mapper.readValue(jsonOutput, ResponseList.class);
```

Comment: why should UTF-8 solve the problem?

Comment: First, you're encoding the whole key value pair instead of encoding only the value, which is probably incorrect. Regarding your question, we have no idea why an unknown server exposing an unknown API returns what it returns.

Comment: Aside from the fact that encoding the *request URL* has nothing to do with the format of the response, your response is completely UTF-8 compliant:  The backslash, `u`, and hex digits are all valid UTF-8 characters.  The escape sequences are perfectly valid JSON, regardless of the JSON’s charset.

Answer (score -1):

This is not problem of encoding, it is problem your data source. Encoding comes into play when you convert bytes into string. You expect encoding to convert **string in form of \uxxxx into another string** which is not going to happen.

The whole point is, that the source of data is serializing data this way so your raw data is gone and is replaced with \uxxxx.

Now you would have to manualy capture \uxxx sequences and convert that to actual characters.

Comment: You mean the input value taken from the web service URL is broken?

Comment: A correct JSON parser will convert the unicode escape sequences to characters automatically. There is absolutely no need to manually capture escape sequences and convert them.

Comment: @JBNizet, please see my edition. Are you suggesting something like the object mapper? I am using "com.fasterxml.jackson"

Comment: Yes, for example. Parsing your JSON with Jackson will transform the unicode escape sequences into the corresponding chinese charcters.

Comment: OK. I am meeting with another issue when using the mapper. I am going to write another story.

Comment: The thing is, this is not character byte encoding issue. Answer is valid. The fact that parser can parse escaped sequences into characters only confirms what I have wrote as it is "doing it by hand" for you.

Comment: @JBNizet, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936445/why-does-my-json-mapper-not-recognize-my-object